# Initialize DefaultRoleProvider connectionstring with code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, roleprovider

I have a wbe app mvc c#4.0, I want to Initialize DefaultRoleProvider  connectionstring from code at runtime (don't want it from web.config).
I created a class MyRoleProvider : DefaultRoleProvider

```
public class MyRoleProvider : DefaultRoleProvider  
{

    public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
    {
        base.Initialize(name, config);

        // Update the private connection string field in the base class.  
        bool IsLocal = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsLocal"] as string);

        string connectionString = "local connectionString ... ";
        if (IsLocal == false)
            connectionString = "prod connectionString ...";
        //ToDo- how to set connection string next property of provider.  
        ??
    }  
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should try dynamically setting the connection string in the configuration, and reload the corresponding section. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework

Comment: I don't have permission to change config file.

Answer (score 0):

On second thought, you could try something based on Reflection, like this :

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : SqlRoleProvider  
{    
    public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
    {  
        base.Initialize(name, config);

    // Update the private connection string field in the base class.  
    bool IsLocal = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsLocal"] as string);

    string connectionString = "local connectionString ... ";
    if (!IsLocal)
    {
        connectionString = "prod connectionString ...";
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo field;
        field = this.GetType()
            .GetField("_sqlConnectionString",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance 
                | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        field.SetValue(this, connectionString);
    }
}
```

-------------------- **Initial post**

I'm afraid the best you can do this way is to dynamically select the connection string name, and refer to another connection already declared in the web.config . Something like this with a class that extends `SqlRoleProvider` :

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : SqlRoleProvider  
{

    public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
    {  
        bool IsLocal = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsLocal"] as string);

        string connectionStringName = "local connectionString name ";
        if (!IsLocal)
            connectionStringName = "prod connectionString name";
        config.Set("connectionStringName", connectionStringName );
        base.Initialize(name, config);
    }  
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: My request started with that I don't have permission to change the web config file :) ... and I want to make my connection string secure inside the code.

Comment: @HaddarMacdasi : The idea would be to mix this with configsource ( see "Using External Configuration Files" in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.80%29.aspx ) I'm afraid the other option is to use some kind of Reflector or Resharper tool to uncompile SqlRoleProvider and use the whole code in your own RoleProvider, modifying the Initialize method

Comment: @HaddarMacdasi : had another idea on the subject, edited my answer